# Write x264_encoder_encode output to file and play it

Tags: libx264

I need to encode a video stream using x264 library and write the output to a file. Here is the code I am using for encoding.

```
x264_param_t    params;
x264_param_default(&params);
x264_param_default_preset(&params,"medium","zerolatency");

params.i_width  = width;
params.i_height = height;
params.i_frame_reference    = 1;
params.rc.i_rc_method       = X264_RC_CRF; //X264_RC_ABR;
params.rc.f_vbv_buffer_init = 0;
params.rc.f_rf_constant = 25;
params.rc.f_rf_constant_max = 35;
params.rc.f_rate_tolerance  = 0.1;
params.rc.b_stat_write      = 0;
params.i_threads        = 1; //0 is auto!!
params.b_sliced_threads     = 0;
params.rc.i_lookahead       = 0;
params.i_sync_lookahead     = 0;
params.i_bframe             = 0;
params.b_annexb         = 1; 
params.b_repeat_headers     = 1;
params.i_fps_den        = 1;
params.b_intra_refresh      = 1;
params.vui.i_chroma_loc     = 0;
params.i_scenecut_threshold = 0;
params.analyse.i_subpel_refine = 6; 

x264_param_apply_profile(&params,"baseline");

// Open encoder
encoder_ = x264_encoder_open(&params);

...

x264_picture_alloc(&pic_, X264_CSP_I420, width, height);

int size = x264_encoder_encode(encoder_, &nals_, &numNals_, &pic_, &picOut_);  

FILE* pFile = NULL;
pFile = fopen("h264Output", "wb");

fwrite( nals_[0].p_payload, size, 1, pFile );
fclose (pFile);

x264_picture_clean(&pic_);
```

After this I try to open h264Output file with ffPlay.exe but it gives the following error:
Invalid data found when processing input.

Can someone help me what am I doing wrong? I had a look at the following post but it didn't help me. [write x264_encoder_encode output nals to h264 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484458/write-x264-encoder-encode-output-nals-to-h264-file)

Comment: I don't see any reason this would not work. Can you share a copy of the h264Output file?

Comment: Is there a way to attach a file in stackoverflow?

Anyway I move a step forward. In pFile = fopen("h264Output", "wb"); I change "wb" with "ab", and the error was gone in ffplay.exe, however instead of displaying video ffplay video shows green screen.
Any idea?

Comment: And ffplay displays the following error:

[h264 @ 03462a80] Missing reference picture, default is 00B f=0/0
[h264 @ 03462a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 022d74c0] mmco: unref short failure

Answer (score 1):

I would delete everything in after `x264_param_default_preset` except

```
params.i_width  = width;
params.i_height = height;
```

and try to open your file with a player like MPlayer. If possible share your dumped file with us. Put it in dropbox or wherever suitable. You can't attach it here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I deleted some of the parameters and the file now plays ok. Thanks for your help.